# Duplicate Global Key in Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have Controllers in my app for every page in this Controllers I have defined a Key

```
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

which i pass it to each page in this way

```
  PendingOrdController pendingOrdController = Get.put(PendingOrdController());

Scaffold(
  key: pendingOrdController.scaffoldKey,
```

Consider I have 3 Pages in my App
And I move through them in this way

```
Page1 => Page2 => Page3 => Page1
```

when I push `Page1` for the second time I get the error

> ```
> Duplicate GlobalKey detected in the widget tree.
> ```

How Can I Fix This? or if my approach is wrong please point me in right direction

EDIT
This a simple usage of Global Key in Controller

```
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    GetCart().then((value) {
    if (value.isSuccessfull ){
      res = value.body;
    }else {
      value.ShowMessage(scaffoldKey);
    }
    });
  }
```

Comment: why not using a separate key for each page instead of getting a global key from the controller?

Comment: @P4yam Mamnon Az pasokhton. Each Page has its own Controller and most usage of global key is inside the Controller. I updated the question with an Example of usage

Comment: khahesh mikonam. Try putting each scaffold key on its page instead of Get controller. Generally, get controller is for none UI-related actions.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution? I am using the same approach as you do.

Comment: @Dabbel the above comment was ok but the best way I find was not to use scaffoldKey at all. getx has everything you need and it does not need scaffoldkey.
if there is any specific thing you need to do tell me I think I might be able to help you